# Why does zero not equate to zero in excel

Tags: excel

I have an index match match formula. When i specifically refresh the index match match formula, it states a result of 0 withiut any decimal points or values. Just 0. So i believe this is not a floating point issue. However, when i use an IF formula which checks if it equates to 0, it comes up with a false. Why is this so? Is there a solution?

Comment: It's likely to be something to the tune of `0.00000000012` in a cell formatted to display three decimal places or less. Try to see what happens when you subtract one zero from the other.

Comment: Perhaps test if less than 1...

Comment: Unfortunately, i cannot upload the file because it is confidential. i have checked the values up to 30 decimal places and yet, it still says 0.0000000... so i dont think it is a floating point error. also, i have made sure that they are all of the same "number" format, though that doesnt seem to bear fruit either. Also, strangely enough, this only applies to "0". If i change the value in the cell to any other number and change the formula to equate it to said number, it works.

Comment: What happens when you divide 1 by this number? Do you get a "division-by-zero" error or do you get an actual value?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is not a number at all so we will need to convert it to an integer for the comparison:

```
=IF(INT(VALUE(A1)) = 0, ... )
```

Comment: @hihihi1029 Ok, it sounds like it isn't even a number. Let's try converting it to a number from whatever it is. Try the new formula

Answer (score 0):

Without having the spreadsheet, it's hard to be sure.

But as others have stated already it could well be a floating point rounding issue.

Another option is that it may be a different data type altogether. Say one of the values is an integer number 0 and the other a string "0". Can look the same in the sheet, but definitely aren't the same.